# Error installing "node-red-contrib-zeromq"

Tags: python, node.js, npm, node-red, apt

I have an error in node red "Flows stopped due to missing node types. zeromq in zeromq out" . And I tried to install the package `node-red-contrib-zeromq` from palette and also from terminal but without success.

The node red app is on a gateway in some "keros linux distribution " pretty similar with Ubuntu. I tried to `apt-get install python-dev` but it doesn't work. Because I don't have `apt-get` installed.

Here is the log in node red debug:
[image: click here to view log]

And  the log when I tried `npm install node-red-contrib-zeromq` (pictures):
[image: click here to view log]

[image: click here to view log]

Comment: Please do not post images, they are hard to read and impossible for people that have to use screen readers. Please post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS and npm require a fully functional Python install and what ever the equivalent to the Debian/Ubuntu build-essential package installed in order to build the native components of any node you may want to install.

How you install these prerequisites depends on your Linux distributions packaging system. I can't find any reference to Keros Linux online so am unable to offer any suggestion here.